# Can I pull a specific commit with composer?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

Is it possible to fetch a certain pull request with composer? Like a specific commit from a fork? What would the directive look like?

**edit: context** This would be helpful so I don't have to wait for a new tag to be created.
 I am certain it will be merged, however I don't know if when then devs will get a chance and I'd rather not put off the work flow I am in...

**edit 2:** now that I think about it, surely when developers make a fork of a public package they might need to test their own fork within a project or two before even pushing a pull request

**edit 3: example** I'm trying to pull this https://github.com/valorin/dispatcher/commit/c566eb6902f378abd59943e7ea09f61e734c8960 to no avail, I tried:

```
    "valorin/dispatcher": "develop#c566eb6902f378abd59943e7ea09f61e734c8960"
```

and

```
    "indatus/dispatcher": "develop#c566eb6902f378abd59943e7ea09f61e734c8960"
```

**edit 4: great success**

```
"require": {
        "indatus/dispatcher": "dev-develop#c566eb6"
}
```

adding the `dev-` prefix did the trick

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't reference a pull request directly, but you can always get hold of a specific commit. You just need to find the commit hash that the pull request introduces. (If you're using github it's in the commits tab).

Then you'll need to use something like this in your composer.json -

```
 "require": {
    "mysoftware/thesoftware": "dev-master#3f38376d"
}
```

Where `mysoftware/thesoftware` is the usual vendor/software name thing you would use, and the part after the '#' on the right-hand side is the specific commit hash you want.

Answer (score 21):

The suggested and approved solution works to download commits already merged on the main repository.

IF YOU WANT TO DOWNLOAD A COMMIT FROM A PULL REQUEST **NOT YET MERGED** you have to follow a different path.

Suppose you have the package `vendor/package` and that "RandomUser" creates a fork on GitHub, creates a new branch `patch-1` and commits to it some editing that you want to test downloading them via composer.

Then, your `composer.json` file has to be written this way:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        ...
        "vendor/package": "dev-patch-1#1234567890",
        ...
    },
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/RandomUser/Package.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, in the `require` section of the `composer.json` file you request the package as usual, BUT you add the specific branch `dev-patch1`, prefixing it with `dev-` to decrease the minimum stability to `dev`, and adding the `#1234567890` the specific commit ID.

Then you also add the specific repository of the user that committed the PR: this makes Composer able to download the git repository, check the existent branches on it, read its `composer.json` file and use it to install you required dependency.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I would add that finally you just need to run `composer update vendor/package`

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you just need the commit ID. Say you want to pull in [this commit to Ardent (Laravel framework, PHP)](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent/commit/9fbe73399d84fc726dc9e122955de444f4fb4901) - you can force it to that commit with

```
"require": {
    "laravelbook/ardent": "master#9fbe73399d84fc726dc9e122955de444f4fb4901"
}
```

To pull from a fork, you just need to specify that fork in the require instead. For example, [this is one of my forks](https://github.com/JoeChilds/Swiftlet/commit/effd5c59f398d56fec261cf1d73a7397cdf78a56) of another repo. To get that commit, I can require this

```
"require": {
    "JoeChilds/Swiftlet": "master#effd5c59f398d56fec261cf1d73a7397cdf78a56"
}
```

Comment: I got this issue: `Could not parse version constraint master#c566eb6902f378abd59943e7ea09f61e734c8960: Invalid version string "master#c566eb6902f378abd59943e7ea09f61e734c8960"`

Comment: Is it a public repo? If so, can you link me to it? :-)

Comment: Trying to pull this https://github.com/valorin/dispatcher/commit/c566eb6902f378abd59943e7ea09f61e734c8960

Comment: It's on the `develop` branch, so you'll need `develop#c566eb6902f378abd59943e7ea09f61e734c8960`. The `master` branch commit is `master#7369a94ef15736e81d8138185a2118a2b4179945`

Comment: Same error though `Invalid version string "develop#c566eb6902f378abd59943e7ea09f61e734c8960"`

Comment: Just been looking at it and got as far as finding that `develop` doesn't work, so Googled that it needed `dev-develop`, came back and saw you'd just got that too heh. Oh well, glad you've got it :)

Comment: This is simply incorrect. "Could not parse version constraint." Wish it worked.