# Laravel - Publish Vendor Class Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media in Spatie to configure it with MongoDB

Tags: laravel, pdo, media, media-library, laravel-medialibrary

here i have a Media class at Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media path. it was creating PDO issues with this code.

```
class Media extends Model implements Responsable, Htmlable
```

so i tried this in there and it worked for the cause.

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Media extends Eloquent implements Responsable, Htmlable
```

now its fine as long its working but what about updating composer will remove everything i guess and PDO problem will appear again. so how can i publish it out there to make it permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you best bet here would be to fork the [spatie/laravel-medialibrary](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) repository. You can then make your changes in your fork and commit them. Then you'll be able to use your commit as the package version in your `composer.json` and your fork as the repository.

For example in your `composer.json` change your `spatie/laravel-medialibrary` requirement to `"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "dev-{your-branch-name}#{your commit hash}",`. And add a `"repositories"` field to your `composer.json` like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/{your github username}/laravel-medialibrary"
    }
]
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878984/can-i-pull-a-specific-commit-with-composer) StackOverflow question for more examples on how to use your own commit in your package. Also have a look at Composer's "Repositories" [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) to see other ways to add repositories (for example to use a local path) and their "Versions#Branches" [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#branches) to see how to specify branches as versions.