# Composer Require a Specific Pull Request

Tags: php, composer-php

I'll like to include a pull request into my project, but i'm having problems doing it on composer. I'm looking to specifically require this particular pull request.

https://github.com/brexis/laravel-workflow/pull/47

What should I "require" in Composer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pull a specific commit with composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878984/can-i-pull-a-specific-commit-with-composer)

Answer (score 16):

You can't require from a specific pull request, but you can require a specific **branch**. Composer's documentation talks about requiring specific branches [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#branches) and using repositories that are not on Packagist  (like your forked repository) [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610532/3486675) shows how to require a specific commit in a specific branch. In your case you could skip the specific commit. You could add your repository as follows to your `composer.json` file:

```
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/personnage/laravel-workflow.git"
    }
```

And you could add your requirement as `"brexis/laravel-workflow": "dev-laravel-58-support"` (branch name):

```
    "require": {
        ...
        "brexis/laravel-workflow": "dev-laravel-58-support",
        ...
    },
```

Run `composer update` to install the dependency. Every time you update your branch (and therefore the pull request), you could run `composer update` again and Composer should fetch the latest commit on that branch.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use the hash `#` character and then specify a specific commit? And isn't a pull request also a "branch" in the sense that you find those under `refs/....`  (use `git-ls-remote(1)` against Microsofts' Github repository)? Wondering if it couldn't work.

Comment: > Isn't it possible to use the hash # character and then specify a specific commit? Yes, as in the linked answer above. > And isn't a pull request also a "branch"...? Not 100% the same thing, but yes, using a branch was my suggestion in the answer above.